# Populate ETS table on application start

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

I am trying to create an elixir/erlang `ets` table and populate it with some data on application start. I see that it is run when started, but may be compile/runtime error?

For example:

```
def start(_type, _args) do
  import Supervisor.Spec

  # Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
  children = [
    DataToETS,
  ]

  opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: App.Supervisor]
  Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
end
```

And then the `DataToETS`:

```
defmodule DataToETS do
  use Task

  def start_link(opts) do
    Task.start_link(DataToETS, :run, [])
  end

  def run do
    # Load to the ETS  
  end

end
```

In my `DataToETS` I do log and it logs. Any idea how to populate and then access when application runs?

Comment: Have you tried creating the table and then populating it in the `init` callback of `DataToETS`? That is the way to go.

Comment: How would this be with using the `start_link` function?

Comment: I see how this can work with the GenServer. But is this the runtime/compile time difference that causes it?

Comment: This will work during runtime, but when the application is starting. If you post your `DataToETS` implementation, I'll be able to better help you out.

Comment: ETS is also tied to the process that calls it. You can either populate the ETS table in your application's `start` callback or a sub-process's `init` callback.

Comment: @Sheharyar thank you I have made the update to include the `DataToETS`. I know that the loading is working I can run it in iex and it loads. just in the start. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you simply want to create a table and populate it once** (without attachment to another sub-process, like `GenServer`), you can just directly do it in the `start/2` callback of your application:

```ex
def start(_type, _args) do
   # Create ETS Table here
   # and seed it with initial data

   # Other stuff...
end
```

---

**If you want to do it exclusively when a sub-process is started,** you can create/populate it in it's `init/1` callback. This is how it would look like for a GenServer:

```ex
defmodule DataToETS do
  def start_link(_args) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    # Create ETS Table here
    # and seed it with initial data
    :ok
  end
end
```

*It would be similar for other processes like Supervisor, Task, GenStage, etc...*

Comment: Ok, that does make sense thanks. I am still unsure why it would work in loading table here in start but not in another function like i had like `run`.

Comment: @PeteJ It’s all about erlang processes. `ETS` is _owned_ by the process. Callbacks (like `start/2` or `init/1` belong to _this_ process, while `run/0` and whatever are just functions executed by the _caller_ process. You should explicitly [pass a table identifier returned by new](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#new-2) to another process to make it available friom there.